# What is it CHAR(107)+CHAR(113) in query of SQLi and how to known full list of those chars?

Tags: sql, security, sql-injection

In sql injection we have a query

```
UNION ALL SELECT CHAR(113)+CHAR(106)+CHAR(122)+CHAR(106)+CHAR(113)+CHAR(110)+CHAR(106)+CHAR(99)+CHAR(73)+CHAR(66)+CHAR(109)+CHAR(119)+CHAR(81)+CHAR(108)+CHAR(88)+CHAR(113)+CHAR(112)+CHAR(106)+CHAR(107)+CHAR(113),NULL--
```

where are this **CHAR(113)+CHAR(106)+CHAR(122)+CHAR(106)**.  Every CHAR is representing a 1 letter, right?
Where to see full list of this letters to CHAR?

Comment: Those are ASCII values and you can google for a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a table of the ASCII character set with the command `man ascii` at a terminal prompt on Linux or MacOS (provided man pages are installed).

Here's a couple of online versions of that table:

- https://www.ascii-code.com/
- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html

Probably this information is also available on Windows, I don't know.